# Best H.264 encoding settings to target low-bandwidth audience

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264

We are building a video streaming website targeting audiences with 56kbps internet connection. We've chosen the H.264 codec to prepare the videos, now there are some challenges:

1) Should we use VBR (Constrained) or CBR? I've read that Constrained VBR will give the best quality for high-quality streaming, but Is this suitable for low-bandwidth connection?

2) Regarding the previous question, what is the most optimal variable or constant data rate for the video streamed to the audiences? and How can this data rate be achieved?

Comment: What frame size is your material? What kind of content? Do you also have audiences with higher bandwidth?

Comment: Since we are targeting mobile devices, the frame size might vary, we have to prepare the video in three standard frame sizes. The content is mostly composed of action scences. We might have audiences with higher bandwidth like 128kbps.